# understanding the rails form input with bootstrap style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, material-design, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to convert this

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="material-icons">email</i>
    </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email...">
</div>
```

into <%= f.text :email %>

The end result should be 
[image]

I tried doing but it didn't look the same

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="material-icons">email</i>
  </span>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Email"%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first one is a `text` input tag, then you can use a `text_field` form helper, to create an input the same way:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email...">

<%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Email..."%>
```